# Is there a gedit plugin that adds search features?

Tags: text-editor, search, gedit, plugins

I'm hoping to add **search and replace within selection** and **search within files**. Having a search option in the context menu would also be handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For searching within files I found this plugin: http://oliver.github.com/gedit-file-search/.

The ability to search and replace only selected text has been requested for years
( https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150010 ) but I haven't found any plugins to do that.

A complete list of gedit plugins: http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins

Comment: I was too slow! I'd say +1 for the extra links.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://oliver.github.com/gedit-file-search/) gedit search plugin what you're looking for?  Instructions to install are on that website.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is really old, but here is a little update. For gedit 3 I would recommend [this plugin advanced-find](http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/) over the gedit-file-search, because I was not able to install the latter with my gedit 3.4.1. Also, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From 16.04 onwards, the `gedit-plugins` package adds a "Find in files..." menu option **into the hamburger menu** (into the same section where the original "Find..." feature is located).

The default directory to search (can be overridden) is the currently active directory in the file-browser panel (provided by the accordingly named core plugin) (the file browser panel can be toggled on/off by <kbd>F9</kbd>).

The search is recursive in subdirectories. Replace feature is not available.

Obtain it with:

```
sudo apt install gedit-plugins
```

Links:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gedit-plugins

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/blob/master/plugins/list-of-gedit-plugins.md

Update:

Found the standalone plugin in the packages inventory; maybe it can be installed on its own? (I can't try, I have already installed the entire set.)

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gedit-plugin-find-in-files